# How to get total steps count (pedometer) for current day only (Gear S2)?

Tags: javascript, html, tizen-wearable-sdk

Looking for a way to get total steps count for current day only.

Using

```
tizen.humanactivitymonitor.setAccumulativePedometerListener
```

I can get `accumulativeTotalStepCount` which is *Accumulative walking and running step count since the device is booted.* according to documentation.

But I not need since device is booted, I need since current day started.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **StepDifference** Interface object available in which you can find the stepdifference based on timestamps.

You can set the timestamp as when the day starts and get the stepdiffernce which will be the currentday count.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do this? The documentation is extremely vague on this point and I cannot find any examples.